# How does pruning help when I will have to traverse complete graph to find the terminal states?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning, minmax

I read about the `minimax` algorithm and then read about `alpha beta pruning`. While I am able to appreciate the idea of pruning, what I am not able to understand is that I still have to know the terminal states / leaf nodes in advance.

To know the terminal states, I will have to draw the complete graph in memory and also traverse each node in advance. Isn't it?

I have a 1-Dimensional 1 X 3 grid in the picture below. So there are 3 columns but 1 row. I took this for easier illustration.

[image]

As you could see, I have calculated each `MIN/MAX` by finding out all the possible states and then traversing each node. While pruning will certainly prevent extra traversal, how is it still beneficial as I have to traverse the complete graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to traverse the full graph as pruning will determine branches that **will not** give you a better solution for sure and "delete" them from graph. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBXHtz4Gbdo) is the video which helped me understand the algo.

Comment: In the video, how are the terminal values calculated?

Comment: By terminal values, I mean the value in leaf-nodes. For example 4,6 .. 7,9 ... and so on.

Comment: The point is that not all terminal values need to be read, since at an earlier stage it might already be clear there are other branches in the tree that are giving better values, whatever that unvisited terminal state is. You don't need to know it as it would not change the outcome.

Comment: Terminal value (leaf value) is evaluated when the node is reached. In the video it is already calculated for educational purposes

Comment: Never realized that they were for educational purposes!!

Comment: yeah at the first look it may be misleading... I've had that luck to learn about the algo at the university, so watched the video to reorganize knowledge :). Have fun!